# How to check if this is the index page in Django?

Tags: python, django

How can I check of the present page is the index page in a Django template?

```
{% if What Goes Here??? %}

// whatever

{% endif %}
```

Comment: where would these template tags be? Wouldn't you be writing your template code in the index page template itself?

Comment: @maz, ha ha ha you're right I can just put the "// whatever" in the index template. I was thinking about putting it in the base for some reason.

Comment: :) no problem, glad I could help. Just added it as an answer below so that you can close out the question.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can just add your template code to the index page template itself.

Comment: what if he use partial template lets pat `header.html` and he need this condition inside it

Answer (score 15):

```
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    'django.core.context_processors.request',
    ...
)


{% if request.path == "/" %}
    ...
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
{% if request.resolver_match.url_name == 'index' %}

// whatever

{% endif %}
```